# Should I use small rocks to disrupt yard erosion?

Tags: landscaping, water, yard, erosion-control

I'm having a problem where rivulets are forming in the lower section of my yard, giving it a fragmented like appearance. I assume this is caused my runoff from the upper section of my yard, which is sloped downwards towards the flat, lower section. The rivulets don't form in the all-grass portion of my yard, but instead form right at the base of a landscaped portion that is entirely composed of various vines and ground cover. At the boundary of this ground-cover portion are large, decorative rocks. My assumption was that I could place a layer of small rocks/rock chips/gravel between the decorative rocks and my grass and this would disrupt the flow of the water and remove the small rivers that I assume are forming and causing the large gashes in the yard.

[image]

I drew the image above to better illustrate the situation.
Would this work and be a good long-term solution?

Comment: Excellent question. My experience with small rocks, especially sharp crushed gravel, is that over time, they migrate to places where you don't want them, and that they are quite hard to totally remove. I've gotten many a bruised foot from these pebbles. Just be sure to consider where the larger 'rivers' will deposit them, *before* you dump 5 cubic yards into your groundcover.